# Variable changing by itself inside loop

Tags: python, loops, variables, matrix

I have a python `for` loop that seems to have a variable changing of its own accord inside the loop. My variables are defined as:

```
yhat = np.empty((1,len(prices)))
yhat[:] = nan
yhat = yhat.astype('float')
e = Q = yhat

P = R = np.matrix(np.zeros((2,2)))
B = np.empty((2,len(prices)))
B[:] = nan
B = np.matrix(B)

B[:,0] = 0
```

The loop is: (`prices` is a dataframe)

```
for t in xrange(0,len(prices),1):

    if t > 0:
        B[:,t] = B[:,t-1]
        R = P+Vw


    yhat[0,t] = x[t,:]*B[:,t]
    print yhat[0,t]

    Q[0,t] = x[t,:]*R*x[t,:].T + Ve
    print yhat[0,t]

    e[0,t] = y[t,0] - yhat[0,t]
    print yhat[0,t]

    K = (R*x[t,:].T)/Q[0,t]

    B[:,t] = B[:,t]+K*e[0,t]


    P = R - K*x[t,:]*R
```

I'm printing `yhat` because I've narrowed the anomaly in the code down to it. After set the value of `yhat` @ t, it seems to change. When I run the code, it prints out:

```
0.0
0.001
20.438747
```

Additionally, I'm concerned about the subtraction for `e[0,t]` because for some reason the subtraction results in the value of `yhat` at that current moment?

Maybe I'm missing something blatantly obvious. I'm relatively new to python, and I switched over from MATLAB.

EDIT: x & y are also matrix objects. So all of the multiplications are matrix dot products.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`e = Q = yhat` won't create copies. They are instead additional *references to the same object*. Altering that object through either the `e` or `Q` names will reflect in those changes being visible through the `yhat` reference too.

So

```
yhat[0,t] = x[t,:]*B[:,t]
```

and

```
Q[0,t] = x[t,:]*R*x[t,:].T + Ve
```

and

```
e[0,t] = y[t,0] - yhat[0,t]
```

all operate on the same, single `numpy` array object, not on separate objects.

Use the [`numpy.copy()` function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.copy.html) to create independent new copies instead:

```
e, Q = np.copy(yhat), np.copy(yhat)
```

Comment: Beautiful. Now the Kalman filter is working like a dream. Now is this just a numpy nuance? Or is there the same result with a pandas dataframe?

Comment: @denbjornen505: this is a *Python* nuance; names are *labels*, references to an object. You can attach as many labels as you like to an object.

Comment: @denbjornen505: see http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html for a great article and presentation about how names in Python work.